# Openshift - ROOT.war deployed but no app

Tags: eclipse, jboss, openshift

That's what I see in my logs:

```
[jbossas-DOMAIN.rhcloud.com SHA]\> tail_all
2014/05/26 09:08:35,527 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4)
JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
2014/05/26 09:08:35,599 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment.connector] (MSC service t
hread 1-2) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
2014/05/26 09:08:35,620 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter] (MSC servi
ce thread 1-2) HornetQ resource adaptor started
2014/05/26 09:08:35,621 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.ResourceAdapterAc
tivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-2) IJ020002: Depl
oyed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
2014/05/26 09:08:35,623 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment.connector] (MSC service t
hread 1-4) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
2014/05/26 09:08:35,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thre
ad 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ROOT.war"
2014/05/26 09:08:38,512 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS01821
0: Registering web context:
2014/05/26 09:08:38,532 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015951
: Admin console listening on http://127.2.148.129:9990
2014/05/26 09:08:38,532 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015874
: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 19348ms - Started 211 of 330 service
s (116 services are passive or on-demand)
2014/05/26 09:08:38,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads -
 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "ROOT.war"
[jbossas-DOMAIN.rhcloud.com SHA]\> find . -name ROOT.war
find: `./.ssh': Permission denied
find: `./.sandbox': Permission denied
./app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossas/deployments/ROOT.war
find: `./.tmp': Permission denied
./app-deployments/2014-05-26_08-49-32.024/dependencies/jbossas/deployments/ROOT.
war
[jbossas-DOMAIN.rhcloud.com SHA]\>
```

But when I go to the root url I see the default `Welcome to your JBoss AS application on OpenShift` page. I am not using maven. Tried to follow the instructions for Jboss (jboss-as-7.1.1.Final) from [this page](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear) - did not delete the `src` folder though. What do I need to do ? Do I need to delete the `src` folder (?) and add a deployments folder ?

Build output (eclipse Java EE Luna M7)

```
Stopping jbossas cartridge
Sending SIGTERM to jboss:301473 ...
Building git ref 'master', commit e48bedf
Skipping Maven build due to absence of pom.xml
Preparing build for deployment
Deployment id is 72c749b6
Activating deployment
Deploying JBoss
Starting jbossas cartridge
Found 127.2.148.129:8080 listening port
Found 127.2.148.129:9999 listening port
/var/lib/openshift/538267574382ece7950004a4/jbossas/standalone/deployments /var/lib/openshift/SHA/jbossas
/var/lib/openshift/538267574382ece7950004a4/jbossas
Artifacts deployed: ./ROOT.war
-------------------------
Git Post-Receive Result: success
Activation status: success
Deployment completed with status: success


Repository already uptodate.
```

EDIT: hmm, the war is 24k which is little - the project is a regular java web application project - runs fine locally both on glassfish and jboss

Comment: So much time later and I am also having this problem. I have Wildfly installed locally and on OpenShift, I publish the same webapp as ROOT.war in both and everything works fine in my computer, but in OpenShift, no webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would accept an answer telling me how to do it from eclipse (edit: asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23938413/281545)) but till then producing manually the war (right click on the project then export as war) and then `scp`'ing straight from git Bash (msysgit, mingwin):

```
$ scp "~/ROOT.war" SHA@APP-DOMAIN.rhcloud.com:/var/lib/\
openshift/SHA/app-root/dependencies/jbossas/deployments
```

as detailed [here](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear) (detailed is an euphemism) solved it.

For the gory details of finally setting this up see [here](http://utumno.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/jboss-on-eclipse-luna/)

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old so I am sure that the problem has been solved, however I was having the same problem and I am sure someone else will do as well. In my case the git wasn't tracking the `src` folder in my local repository.

You just need to open up a terminal in your git repo folder and type `git status` to show which folders are not being tracked, then `git add [file/foldername]` and finally republish it.